# Relation between growth rate of GDP and real interest rate for sustainable debt-to-GDP ratio

Tags: gdp, government-debt, debt

Why is the relation between the growth rate of GDP and the real interest rate important for sustaining the government the debt-to-GDP ratio ?

Comment: It rather depends on other factors such as the primary deficit or surplus as a proportion of GDP